# How to change only one widget and leave the others the same with GWT's built in MVP-framework?

Tags: gwt, gwt-mvp

I'm just getting started using the built in MVP framework in GWT 2.1 and I have, what I think, a very simple question.
When I read the official tutorial [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) or look at the gwt-plattform example [here](http://gwtpsample.appspot.com/#main), one view always replaces another view.
But what if I want to have a specific widget on all my "pages".
As an example you can take the bar at the top of this page, with the StackExchange-logo, your user name and so on. That bar is the same on all pages you can visit, whether you look at a question or a user profile.
How would I get something similar with the MVP-framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the RootPanel as the Activities' container, lay your header panel and SimplePanel inside the RootPanel and use the SimplePanel for your Activities.